# TypeScript model export interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I am new in TypeScript and I just want to ask about the code the (position) is from another model TypeScript because

All are in model folder:

```
export interface Group {
   name: string;
   opportunities: Opportunity[];
}
```

**`opportunity.model.ts`**

```
export interface Opportunity {
   name: string;
}
```

This is the content of my `company.model.ts` in model folder

```
  export interface Company {
   companyName: string;
   position: opportunity;  // my question is here? what should I put here,
                           // because the content of position is the
                           // opportunity which is like a dropdown
   contactNumber: number;
}
```

Thanks. I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: In `Company`, why is `opportunity` lower-case? The case matters.

Comment: You have no type called opportunity defined. Typescript does type checking, and opportunity != Opportunity ... Does this compile?

Comment: I don't know what to put there in the "opportunity" because the content of that position is from another model typescript.

Comment: for example when using enum you just have to do is import the entities where it came from like this    
```
import {Relation} from "./entities/Family"
export interface Family{ relation: Relation;}```

Answer (score 0):

Without much more context if feels like you are looking for something like this:

```
export interface Group {
        name: string;
        opportunities: Opportunity[];
     }
    
    
    
     export interface Opportunity {
        name: string;
     }
    
    
    export interface Company {
       companyName: string;
       position: Opportunity[];  // my question is here? what should I put here,
                               // because the content of position is the
                               // opportunity which is like a dropdown
       contactNumber: number;
    }
```